# Finding $G'(2)$ when $G(x) = \int_0^x h(t) \ dt$

Tags: calculus

Let $$G(x) = \int_0^x h(t) \  dt$$ This is the graph of $h$.

[image: graph]
I need to find the value of $G'(2)$.

I've looked around and read about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I haven't found anything that will help me solve this problem. I'm just not sure how to start it.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, what is $G'$ as a function equal to?

Comment: Exactly......... @DL123

Comment: Defacing your post is not exactly respectful of the people who took the time to provide you with an answer.

Comment: I have rolled back the post to the prior version. It is best to let the post stay, in case anyone else has this question or one like it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** By the Fundamental Theorem we have that $$G'(x) = h(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $G'(x)=h(x)$.

So the value of $G'(2)$ will be equal to $h(2)$ .

Can you find which the value of $h(2)$ is, looking at the graph?